How should I satisfy this last condition from this problem? (Please check my work).
Use an appropriate theorem to show that the origin is a centre for the differential equation $\ddot{x}-x\lvert x \rvert\dot{x}+x^3=0$.
Here's my work: Proof:
Consider the differential equation $\ddot{x}-x\lvert x \rvert\dot{x}+x^3=0$.
By theorem, the origin is a centre for the equation $\ddot{x}+f(x)\dot{x}+g(x)=0$, or for the equivalent system $\dot{x}=y, \dot{y}=-f(x)y-g(x)$, when, in some neighbourhood of the origin, $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and
(i) $f(x)$ is odd, and of one sign in the half-plane $x>0;$
(ii) $g(x)>0, x>0,$ and $g(x)$ is odd (implying $g(0)=0$);
(iii) $g(x)>\alpha f(x)F(x)$ for $x>0$, where $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du$, and $\alpha>1$.
Let $f(x)=-x\lvert x \rvert$ and $g(x)=x^3$ be continuous functions where $\lvert x \rvert$ is sufficiently small.
Note that $f(x)=-x\lvert x \rvert$ is odd because $\lvert f(x) \rvert=\lvert -x \vert x \rvert \rvert$ is even, given that $\lvert f(-x) \rvert=\lvert -f(x) \rvert=\lvert f(x) \rvert$ from the definition of an odd function, so clearly $f(x)=-x\lvert x \rvert<0$ for $x>0$.
This implies that the first condition (i) is satisfied because $f(x)=-x\lvert x \rvert$ is odd and of one sign in the half-plane $x>0$.
Similarly, observe that $g(x)=x^3$ is odd because $g(-x)=(-x)^3=-(x^3)$, which implies that $g(-x)=-g(x), \forall x$ in the domain of $g$.
This gives $g(x)=x^3>0$ for $x>0$ and $g(0)=0$ because $(0)^3=0$.
Hence, the second condition (ii) is satisfied because $g(x)=x^3>0$ for $x>0$, and $g(x)=x^3$ is odd, implying that $g(0)=0$.
Now we will find $F(x)$ where $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du$ for $x>0$.
Since $f(x)=-x\lvert x \rvert$ where $\lvert x \rvert$ is sufficiently small, it follows that $f(u)=-u\lvert u \rvert$ where $\lvert u \rvert$ is sufficiently small, so we get that $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du\implies F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}-u\lvert u \rvert du=[-\frac{u^3\operatorname{sgn}(u)}{3}]_{0}^{x}$, which gives us $F(x)=\frac{-x^3\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{3}$, for $x>0$.
By definition, the sgn (signum) function of the real variable $x$ is defined as $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=-1$ for $x<0$.
Thus, $F(x)=-\frac{x^3}{3}$ because $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=1$ for $x>0$, and $g(x)>\alpha f(x)F(x)\implies x^3>\alpha(-x\lvert x \rvert)(-\frac{x^3}{3})\implies x^3>\alpha(\frac{x^4\lvert x \rvert}{3})\implies x^3>\frac{\alpha x^5}{3}$ since $\lvert x \rvert=x$ for $x>0$.
Finally, we have $x^3>\frac{\alpha x^5}{3}\implies 1>\frac{\alpha x^2}{3}$.
From here, I don't think the inequality of $1>\frac{\alpha x^2}{3}$ is true for $x>0, \alpha>1$ because one counterexample that I can come up with is $\alpha=6, x=1$. May anyone please check/verify/confirm my work/proof above and tell me what's wrong in here and how I should revise this proof in order to satisfy the third condition?

As you found, your desired inequality is $x^3 > \alpha x^5/3$.
For any $\alpha > 0$, this is true when $0 < x < 1/\sqrt{\alpha}$. Of
course it's not true for all $x > 0$, but you only need it to be true in some interval $0 < x < r$: the key phrase is "in some neighbourhood of the origin" in the statement of the theorem.  Remember, we're talking about whether the origin is a centre for the differential equation, and that is a local property: it is only about the behaviour of the solutions in a neighbourhood of the origin, so what happens for large $x$ is irrelevant.

Thank you so much for your help!
